# Looking for sanitized Palo Alto FW Config

Tags: firewall, palo-alto, ciscoconfparse

This may sound a bit unusual, but I'm looking for someone who can answer with a sanitized Palo Alto FW text configuration with the following features used:

- address-groups & service-groups
- global-protect VPN portals
- bgp routing
- high-availability

This configuration will be used to test [ciscoconfparse](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse) config parsing.

I'm looking for the whole config.  Passwords / snmp-communities / sensitive-ip info changed but not removed.  Lab or prod FW configs are fine.  Please indicate what firmware version the config is from.

Comment: Nice. I'll have to give that a shot one day.  Are you planning on adding FortiOS support?

Comment: I haven't considered it yet... I look for all kinds of configs to test parsing with... from what I see, FortiOS looks like a Cisco IOS style config so it probably would be fairly easy to add.  Historically I've had a few more problems parsing brace-delimited configs like Palo Alto, but I'm hoping that those issues are fixed.  I'm asking for this config so I can add Palo Alto parsing unit tests

Comment: JunOS/VyOS/Vyatta are probably pretty close to what Palo Alto looks like, since those are brace delimited.

Comment: I have JunOS and F5 configs... I care about extracting information from those configs and there are subtle syntax unique to each... for instance, there were [certain f5 elseif configs broken for a while](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/issues/70) because of goofy brace parsing.  Palo Altos are popular enough that they need their own tests